# Multi Stage with Zend Framework - If we need a ROOT_DIR defined, can we have it on application.ini?

Tags: zend-framework

On our application.ini file we have set two environment variables:
development and production.

All database details for each ENV are configured there.

**Is it ok and possible to define our ROOT_DIR for each environment on application.ini as well ?**

**Update:**

At the moment on my zend project roots, I have a file called

> config_root.php

and, there I have:

`define('ROOT_DIR',"/home/myuser/www/www");`

Every time I have to switch from development to production, I have to recall to NOT overwrite this same file on the production side, because there, this file is different, and like so instead:

```
define('ROOT_DIR',"/home/productionuser/public_html/");
```

This config_root method is something that I've used. 
At this moment, I'm trying to change how things work around here, and, so I've defined some document roots on my apache configurations. (something that I didn't before).

So, and before continue, a question arrives:

**1 - Since I'm using apache document root configuration, can I, perhaps, drop this ROOT_DIR definition?**

If I still have to use this ROOT_DIR definition, then:

**2 - Can we deal with this inside application.ini and remove the need for config_root.php ?**

Thanks

Comment: hmm... I'm I saying something silly? If so, please say so, I can reformulate. Np at all. :) Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by ROOT_DIR, and what kind of things do you want to be different about this between different environments?

Comment: @Tim Fountain: Thanks a lot. I've added more information. If it's still not clear, or some more information is needed, I will provide it. np at all. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tim Fountain - I've changing my strange English way of writing to something, that I believe, it's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions:

> 1. Since I'm using apache document root configuration, can I, perhaps, drop this ROOT_DIR definition?

Yes, I would think so. You said you have config_root.php in the root directory of each of your ZF projects, so can't you just set ROOT_DIR to `./` (or possibly `./public` if that's what you're trying to get to.

As an example, the default public/index.php that Zend_Tool creates includes this line:

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH') || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

this sets a constant `APPLICATION_PATH` with the full path to the current project's application directory, without this path having to be hard-coded in.

> 2 - Can we deal with this inside application.ini and remove the need for config_root.php ?

I'm not sure if application.ini is the right place for it, but you certainly don't need a separate config_root.php file. If you can use a relative path as in my example above you should be able to build it into your application code without needing separate values for production and development.

Comment: Thanks! I've successfully used zend tool and the application appeared on the dev shared host server. So, all went well. No need for that extra file any more. :)